# jquery - accessing audio files in different folders

Tags: jquery, audio

In an English-Thai language site, I want to store audio files for each page in different folders.
I'm putting at the top of each page a p element (display: hidden) containing the path for that page. Like this:

```
<p id="pathVar">/audio/example_page</p>
```

I want to use this path info to build up the path for the audio files for each page
The jquery code below works (other questions have been posted on this).

```
var audioIsPlaying = false;
var pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML;

jQuery("span").click(function (evnt) {
 if(audioIsPlaying !== true) {
  var elementId = evnt.target.id;
  var oggVar = "/templates/beez_20/audio/"+elementId+".ogg"; 
  var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
  audioElement.setAttribute("src", oggVar);    
  audioElement.play();
  audioIsPlaying = true;
  audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    audioIsPlaying = false;    
   });
 };
});
```

I've checked the pathVar value and it returns /templates/beez_20/audio/ But substituting var oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg";  doesn't work.

Any help would be most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Please  include $(document).ready(function()
    {
function

Comment: $.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
  var audioIsPlaying = false;
  $("span").click(function (evnt) {
    if(audioIsPlaying !== true) {
      var elementId = evnt.target.id;
      var pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML;     
      var oggVar = pathVar+elementID+".ogg";
      var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
      audioElement.setAttribute("src", oggVar);    
      audioElement.play();
      audioIsPlaying = true;
      audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        audioIsPlaying = false;    
      });
    };
  });
});    Thanks :)

Comment: Solved it, elementID instead of elementId in  var oggVar = pathVar+elementID+".ogg";   typo I missed. Sorry to bother you guys :)